# URLs of Azure Static Website should work without trailing /

Tags: regex, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn

I've created an Azure Static Website which works based on the Azure Blob Storage. 
To be able to manage the automatic redirect from HTTP to HTTPs I created Azure CDN with Azure Verizon Premium subscription and I created an endpoint which
points to the URL of the static website. I followed the steps from [this tutorial](https://blog.lifeishao.com/2017/05/24/serving-your-static-sites-with-azure-blob-and-cdn)

If you hit the URL e.g.

```
https://blah.com/foo/
```

You will be automatically redirected to

```
https://blah.com/foo/index.html
```

This is because I set the Index document name to `index.html` in the Static website configuration panel.

What I want to achieve is to add the /index.html symbol to the very end of URL if it doesn't have an extension e.g.

```
https://blah.com/foo
https://blah.com/bar/foo
```

The expected result would be a redirect to:

```
https://blah.com/foo/index.html
https://blah.com/bar/foo/index.html
```

So my idea was to open the https://cdn.windowsazure.com/http/rules/default.aspx and try to create a new Rule; `feature`-> `URL Redirect`. In the TextBox near the `Source` label, I tried to specify the condition using Regex expression `^[^.]+$` which checks if the path contains a `.` If yes then it would mean the URL points to file with extension and the `/index.html` should be added to the end of URL. I think my Regex expression is wrong and should be different. Or maybe it is not the best way to achieve what I want?
Any ideas?
Cheers
[image: The screenshoot]

Comment: Probably, `^.*/[^/.]+$` is safer: after last `/`, there can be 1+ chars other than `/` and `.`.

Comment: ill try this! To apply the single change in the Rules Engine I have to wait couple of hours ;/

Comment: I was also thinking about .+\/[^\.]\w+$

Comment: `.+\/[^\.]\w+$` matches up to the last `/` (that cannot be the first char), then matches any char but a dot, and then matches 1 or more letters, digits or `_` till the end of a string.

Comment: #Wiktor Stribiżew for some reason `^.*/[^/.]+$` doesn't work in Azure Verizon. Maybe it's a matter of regular expression flavor? I don't know what type of regular expression engine does Azure Verizon uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tried almost everything and in the end, after adding this rule the Azure Static Webiste worked as expected:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just further to this as I know it has an accepted answer but you won't need any redirect rule for index.html if you use a custom origin and use the static website's primary endpoint (will be something like .z8.web.core.windows.net/). For whatever reason, the CDN will treat that as a web server rather than a vanilla storage place.